# Is React loading all components first opening page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an app and using `react-router-dom`. When I looking to React Chrome Tool showing main element and all other elements. My homepage loading  `<Home />` component but in the Chrome Tool showing `<Operations />` or `<Changelogs />` e.g. (But browser showing only home component). Is this a problem or not ?  .

I tried `<Link exact path='/' component={Home} />` with exact but nothing changed.

**index.js**

```
const routing = (
    <Router>
        <SidebarComp/>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/operations/:id' exact component={Operations} />
    </Router>
)
```

**React Chrome Ext. Output (With Load Page)**

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Router>
   <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
   <Route path='/operations/:id' exact component={Operations} />
 </Router>
</BrowserRouter>
```

So, this routing loading all components and element with page loading. Does this lead to loss of performance in the future or is this usage wrong?

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question? I don't understand what exactly you're asking.

Comment: App is loading all components and elements with first load. Is this normal or not?

Comment: I think so. I don't know what your expected output is? If you want to do lazy loading, you have to implement it yourself I think, it's not built into React or React Router

Comment: This is expected. There is nothing you can do. Better ignore.

Comment: Yeah, I did a little research, and as you said @FurkanO that's expected behavior. Thanks for the answers.